# How to fix Db after invalid column name, and migration failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I added properties to the ApplicationUser.cs (which I've done before) and everything exploded. This class extends IdentityUser. When I comment out the properties everything appears to work fine. What did I do wrong?

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string LGID { get; } = "";
        public string CoIDs { get; } = "";

        public string LGIDSuperUserName { get; set; } = "unknown"; //new
        public bool IsSuperUser { get; set; } = false;  //new

        public ApplicationUser() { }

        public ApplicationUser(ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
            foreach (Claim c in claims)
            {
                if (c.Type == "LGID")
                    LGID = c.Value;
                if (c.Type == "CoIDs")
                    CoIDs = c.Value;
                if (c.Type == "LGIDSuperUser")
                    LGIDSuperUserName = c.Value;
                if (c.Type == "IsSuperUser")
                    IsSuperUser = c.Value.ToLower()=="yes";
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**More info if needed. Not sure whats relevant here**

When I go to login to my site I first got an error that suggested I needed to migrate the DB. In NuGet Package Manager I ran:

```
Add-Migration ApplicationDbContext
Update-Database
```

Now the error message when I try to login says:

```
Invalid column name 'IsSuperUser'.

var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Here is my Migrations folder inside VisualStudio:
[image]

Comment: are you using entity framework migrations? You should probably add a tag for that

Comment: Probably your new column properties are not reflected in migration process due to incorrect `Database.SetInitializer` setting, or you're not setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` in `Configuration` class inside `Migration` folder. You can include both of them to let us check problem source.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto where would I find the `Configuration` class? I looked through All the file sin the Data folder and did not find that class name

Comment: How about your `Database.SetInitializer` setting? The message indicates newly added column properties not included in table because corresponding table structure still not updated. Since you didn't find `Configuration` class in `Migration` folder (check all .cs files to make sure), try revert previous migration, enable automatic migrations then add new properties.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Any chance you could explain how to do that? I keep googling old answers that say use `Get-Migrations` but that doesnt exist on EFCore anymore apparently